# Variance of the square variation process

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $X = (X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ a square integrable $(\mathcal{F_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$-martingale. The predictable process $\langle X \rangle_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \Bigl(\mathbf{E}\bigl[X_i^2\vert \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\bigr] - X_{i-1}^2\Bigr)$ is called the *square variation process* of $X$.

My question is why the following holds: 
$$\mathbf{E}\bigl[\langle X \rangle_n\bigr] = \mathbf{Var}[X_n - X_0]$$

I guess I know the answer:

We use the telescoping property of the sum:

$$\mathbf{E}\bigl[\langle X \rangle_n \bigr]= \mathbf{E}\biggl[\sum_{i=1}^n \Bigl(\mathbf{E}\bigl[X_i^2\vert \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\bigr] - X_{i-1}^2\Bigr)\biggr] = \sum_{i=1}^n \Bigl(\mathbf{E}\bigl[\mathbf{E}\bigl[X_i^2\vert \mathcal{F}_{i-1}\bigr]\bigr] - \mathbf{E}\bigl[X_{i-1}^2\bigr]\Bigr) = \\
\sum_{i=1}^n \Bigl(\mathbf{E}\bigl[X_i^2\bigr] - \mathbf{E}\bigl[X_{i-1}^2\bigr]\Bigr)= \mathbf{E}\bigl[X_n^2\bigr] - \mathbf{E}\bigl[X_0^2\bigr]\, .$$

Using the tower property and the martingale property we obtain that $$\mathbf{E}\bigl[X_n X_0\bigr] =\mathbf{E}\Bigl[\mathbf{E}\bigl[X_n X_0|\mathcal{F}_0\bigr]\Bigr]=\mathbf{E}\Bigl[X_0\,\mathbf{E}\bigl[X_n |\mathcal{F}_0\bigr]\Bigr] = \mathbf{E}\bigl[X_0^2\bigr]\, .$$ We also know that since $X_n$ is a martingale its expectation is constant, i. e. $\mathbf{E}\bigl[X_n\bigr] = \mathbf{E}\bigl[X_0\bigr]$, so 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{Var}\bigl[X_n - X_0\bigr] &= \mathbf{E}\bigl[(X_n - X_0)^2\bigr] - \mathbf{E}\bigl[X_n - X_0\bigr]^2 \\ & = \mathbf{E}\bigl[(X_n - X_0)^2\bigr]\\
&=\mathbf{E}\bigl[X_n^2\bigr] - 2\,\mathbf{E}\bigl[X_n X_0\bigr] + \mathbf{E}\bigl[X_0^2\bigr] \\
&= \mathbf{E}\bigl[X_n^2\bigr] - \mathbf{E}\bigl[X_0^2\bigr] \,.\;
\end{align}
$ \square$

Is that right?

Please answer if you know it, this is very important for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is correct. Maybe in the third line of the computation of $\mathbf{Var}\bigl[X_n - X_0\bigr]$, I would refer (and give a name to) the displayed equation where $\mathbf{E}\bigl[X_n X_0\bigr]$ is computed.

Comment: Thank you again. If you could also take a look at the linked post? That would be so nice!